# How to update table query in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

How can I convert `Query[MappedProjection[Example, (Option[String], Int, UUID, UUID)], Example, Seq]` to `Query[Examples, Example, Seq]`?

**Details**

I am trying to drop a column from an existing table(`Examples` in this case) and move the data to another table (`Examples2` in this case). I don't want to change all the existing code base, so I plan to join these two tables and map the results to `Example`.

```
import slick.lifted.Tag
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import java.util.UUID

case class Example(
  field1: Option[String] = None,
  field2: Int,
  someForeignId: UUID,
  id: UUID,
)

object Example

class Examples(tag: Tag) extends Table[Example](tag, "entityNotes") {
  def field1 = column[Option[String]]("field1")
  def field2 = column[Int]("field2")
  def someForeignId = column[UUID]("someForeignId")
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  
  def someForeignKey = foreignKey(
    "someForeignIdToExamples2",
    someForeignId,
    Examples2.query,
  )(
    _.id.?
  )
  
  def * =
    (
      field1.?,
      field2,
      someForeignId,
      id,
    ) <> ((Example.apply _).tupled, Example.unapply)
}

object Examples{
  val query = TableQuery[Examples]
}
```

Basically, all the functions in the codebase call `Examples.query`. If I update that `query` by joining two tables, the problem will be solved (of course with a performance shortcoming because of one extra join for each call).

To use the query with the existing code base, we need to keep the type the same. For example, we we can use filter as follows:

```
val query_ = TableQuery[Examples]
val query: Query[Examples, Example, Seq] = query_.filter(_.field2 > 5)
```

Everything will work without a problem since we keep the type of the query as it is supposed to be.

However, I cannot do that with a join if I want to use data from the second table.

```
val query_ = TableQuery[Examples]
val query = query
                .join(Examples2.query_)
                .on(_.someForeignId === _.id)
                .map({
                  case (e, e2) =>
                    ((
                      e2.value.?,
                      e1.field2,
                      e2.id
                      e.id,
                    ) <> ((Example.apply _).tupled, Example.unapply))
                })
```

This is where I got stuck. Its type is `Query[MappedProjection[Example, (Option[String], Int, UUID, UUID)], Example, Seq]`.

Can anyone help? Btw, we don't have to use `map`. This is just what I got so far.

Comment: Does the existing code that expects a `Query[Examples, Example, Seq]` actually care about the first type parameter? Could you make it polymorphic on that parameter? If you can't I don't think it's possible

Comment: `query` is called in many different places. I don't want to change them. That is my real purpose. So, calling other `join`s and `filter`s should be possible after this operation. I gave `Query[Examples, Example, Seq]` as the target shape because I know that the `filter` example works and that is its shape.

Comment: Can you share an example for making it polymorphic on that parameter? Or a link would also help.